# ksh - loop through directory to remove file based on part of file name

Tags: ksh, rm

I am a new ksh developer and have a task to remove files from a directory based on two criteria. Each file name follows this pattern 1-12345-sometext.dat

What I need is to be able to delete all of the .dat files with the first number equaling each other.

For example the files in my directory could be:

```
1-12345-sometext.dat
1-15467-sometext.dat
1-97564-sometext.dat
1-34978-sometext.dat
2-98341-sometext.dat
2-75469-sometext.dat
Somefile.csv
```

What I need to do is delete all the files in the directory with 1 as the prefix and .dat as the extension.

I don't know where to begin, so I have no code to show.

Comment: Can you explain why you must `rm 1*txt` here and not the files starting with a 2?

Comment: your description is unclear (IMHO) "delete all of the .dat files with the first number equaling each other" . So the 2-9* and 2-7* are dat files, and they begin with the "first number equaling each other". Why don't you want to delete them? I agree with WalterA, can't you just use `rm 1*txt`? Good luck!

Answer (score 1):

This script will delete your files, based on your criteria:

```
for file in `ls | grep '^\([0-9]\)-\1[0-9]\{4\}-[a-z]\+\.dat$'`
do
    rm -fv ${file}
done
```

Basically, it lists all files and then filters them based on the given criteria. There it checks for names which match the following condition:

- 1st and second digit has to be equal (+ there is a dash between)
- after the 2nd digit there will be 4 more digits
- then there will be a "dash" and a lower case text with at least one character

After that iterates over the result set and deletes the file one by one.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks for your input.  It gave me direction on where to go. I decided to go with user input and this is my solution.

```
#!/bin/ksh
umask 003

cycleID=$1
User=$2
SrcDir=$3

for i in ${SrcDir} -name "${cycleID}*${User}.dat";
do 
    fileArray=${i};
done

for i in ${fileArray[@]}; 
do 
    rm -f ${SrcDir}${i};
done
```

Comment: glad you solved your problem and posted  your solution. I don't think the `umask` at the top is providing any function, that only affects the permissions mask on files that are created in that script. Did you try it without that? Good luck.

Answer (score 0):

Your solution (@staples) gave away a clue what you want:
Remove files starting with a number given by input.
When you want this in a script using parameters, you can use

```
#!/bin/ksh
if [ $# -ne 3 ]; then
   echo "Usage: $0 cycle_id pattern dir"
   exit 1
fi

cycleID=$1
pattern=$2
dir=$3

if [ ! -d "${dir}" ]; then
   echo "Your third parameter ${dir} is not a directory"
   exit 1
fi
# Exercise: You can add checks on cycleId and pattern

# show remove command
set -x
rm -f "${dir}"/${cycleId}-*-${pattern}.dat
# turn off verbose set -x
set -
```